# Bash Script not killed after it kills the PGID of its own and all its child processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, kill

script_sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for sig in 13 15 18; do
    trap "kill -9 -$$;" $sig
done

hive -f hivescript.hql & 
PID=$!

while [ `ps ${PID} | wc -l` -gt 1 ]
do
    echo waiting
    sleep 5
done
```

There is a utility which will call this sample_script.sh and when I interrupt the script's execution via this utility, the script receives SIGNAL 13 (SIGPIPE).

On receiving the signal, hive process gets killed as it lies in the same process group id as the sample_script.sh. However the script keeps running along with the sleep command.

```
testuser 36223     1  0 13:13 ? 
     <sleep also runs> as child of 36223
```

I have also noticed that at times the hive process is also not killed but the behavior is random.

1. Why does the kill -9 -PGID not kill the script itself. -- Happens always
2. Any guesses why the child process is also not killed at times  -- Random

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: The problem is that when `script_sample.sh` is launched via another script, its pgid is the pid of its parent rather than its own pid.

This modified script should work as you want, by explicitly asking `ps` for the pgid, with the caveat that the trap should now kill the parent script too, and anything else it called, so use with caution!

```
#!/bin/bash
mypgid=`ps -o pgid $$ | tail -1 | sed 's/ //g'`
for sig in 13 15 18; do
    trap "kill -9 -$mypgid;" $sig
done
...
```

**Question 2**: not sure, my fix solves question 1, but the child process still usually survives. I've tried adding `kill -9 $PID;` to your trap, setting it after starting `hive`, and yet my child process (sleep in my experiments) still usually survives. It's as if it got itself into an unkillable stable, which I did not know was possible against a `kill -9`. Note that if I ^C the parent, my child sleep survives, but if I `kill -13` the `script_sample.sh` process, then my child sleep process dies. I don't understand why.

**Other partial solutions**

I've looked for safer solutions, with the intent to run `script_sample.sh` in its own pgid group and not have the trap kill the parent script, but I have not had any luck yet.

I thought of using `setsid`, which should let me start processes in a new session, but it doesn't change the pgid the way I would have wanted.

I thought of using `set -m` at the top of `script_sample.sh`, which makes every command it runs start in a new pgid (then the trap has to `kill -9 -$PID` and also `kill -9 $$`). The trap now behaves correctly but the whole thing misbehaves in new creative ways, making it much harder to kill the parent - somehow it seems this causes the parent to no longer signal `script_sample.sh` when it gets killed, and it causes the parent to ignore ^C.

Despite all this partial information, I am posting this answer because I have at least answered question 1, which I hope is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Joanis. But as you said:The problem is that when script_sample.sh is launched via another script, its pgid is the pid of its parent rather than its own pid. But I am not sure if thats the case...
```
sshd,25853,25846 -sh,25854,25854 /home/sample_script.sh -java,25860,25854 -Xmx16384m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CM |-{java},27035,25854
```

Comment: If you want to know for sure, add `echo mypgid=$mypgid pid=$$` just after setting that variable. Without your `ps` command, I don't know if you're showing me ppid, session ID or pgid.

Comment: @Sparrow I know this didn't fully solve your problem so I won't suggest accepting the answer, but if it was helpful, would you consider upvoting it?